# Converting Python.Runtime.PyObject (Pythonnet) to C# native data types - it works for double but not for numpy.array

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, numpy, python.net

Let's say that I will call a python 3.0 script from C# using Pythonnet. As long as the return is of type double it is pretty simple:

```
var input1 = new double[] {15, 20, 25};
dynamic test = Py.Import("Py_file_name");
double r1 = test.function_name(input1);
```

The value returned from `function_name()` method is converted to double and I can work with it as I want. But with more complicated code, the things go different, lets say, the `retun` is a `numpy.array`:

```
double [] r1 = test.function_name(input1);
```

Fails with the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Python.Runtime.PyObject' to 'double []'`.
I can get the value to object like this:

```
object r1 = test.ANN1_fun(input1);
```

But this do not solve anything, as I still have variable of type `object {Python.Runtime.PyObject}` and I cannot (I don't know how) use it in my C# project. How to convert this numpy.array to any C# array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more like workaround than solution but I will leave it here, in case someone will deal similar problem in future. It seems that Pythonnet handle seamless only basic data types. So you must convert numpy array to something simpler, like list, on the python site, so assuming y1 is `numpy array`:

```
y1=y1.flatten('C') #Only if required by dimensions
y1= [arr.tolist() for arr in y1] #Converting to list
return y1
```

Now you can catch your value in C#

```
double [] r1 = test.function_name(input1);
```

And it will be converted correctly to C# array.